# Entity Framework Code First: "The specified table 'foo' was not found in the model."

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.3

Haven't seen this error before, and a cursory web search turns up very little. Here's (I think) the offending code:

```
this.HasMany(a => a.ListItems).WithRequired()
    .Map(m =>
        {
            m.MapKey("AttributeId");
            m.ToTable("ProductAttributeListItem");
        }
    )
;
```

And here's the full error:

> The specified table 'ProductAttributeListItem' was not found in the
>   model. Ensure that the table name has been correctly specified.

The table is there and spelled correctly.

The lack of search results makes me think I'm missing something obvious. What might that be?

Answer (score 6):

If you want to define the table name of the entity `ListItems` is refering to you need to do that on the entity, not in the relationship mapping:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ListItem>() // or whatever the entity is called
    .ToTable("ProductAttributeListItem");
```

And remove `m.ToTable` from the `Map` action.

Comment: This worked. Strangely I was previously working with SqlExpress and had specified `.ToTable("foo").MapKey("bar")` for mapping and it was working fine. Moving to Sql Enterprise changed something and it started complaining about `Table not found`.